# cookies with getBitmapFromURL()

Tags: android, android-image, android-bitmap

I am passing the url to get the images from the server e.g.

```
getBitmapFromURL("http://abc.xyz.in/logo.jpg");
```

But it is not returning anything. Saying that images are private. So my question is that is there anyway to pass the cookie to getBitmapFromURL() method. So that i can get the images. Or any other alternative is there? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try using https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: i want to pass the cookie with the url then only i can get the data so what should i do?

Comment: You cant do that directly, try using an http connection and get the bytes and cast it into bitmap

Comment: @GirishNair please explain little bit as a answer.

Comment: Your question is `is there anyway to pass the cookie to getBitmapFromURL()` the answer is no, So you have to make an HTTP post request with the cookie to access it, I dont find any other way or try contacting nostra of https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader to do this for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer. I can do this by using following line:

```
connection.addRequestProperty("key", value);
```

Answer (score 1):

2014, if the answer is feasible to you please raise the answer and points

This should do the trick:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add the internet permission and any other permission which is needed in your manifest.

Comment: Same thing  i am doing still not getting anything because my file path is private. So i need to pass the cookie.

Comment: hey i think you can use volley library, please have a look in the given link. hope it will help you https://github.com/smanikandan14/Volley-demo